# Setting default field values in apex for new objects

Tags: visualforce, default-value

We need to set some default values *in apex* on a custom object *before* it is created. The user should ideally work with the standard object page - we don't want to re-create the whole page in visualforce if not necessary.

---

#### Approach 1

Redirect the 'New' button to a custom VF page which loads the defaults and passes them on to the standard page via redirect using URL parameters.

Page (partial):

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="MyObj__c"
    extensions="MyObjController"
    action="!redirectDefaults">
```

Controller (partial):

```
public PageReference redirectDefaults() {
    string defName = someComplexLogic();
    PageReference retPage = new PageReference('/a0H/e?Name' + defName);
    return retPage.setRedirect(true);
}
```

**Question:** The problem here is that fields must be passed in a locale specific format : you have to know the user locale and then pass mm/dd/yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy as the case may be. How can this be done?

---

#### Approach 2

Re-create the page in visual force as an extension of a standard controller. This is more work but I assume there must be a way to initialise an instance of `myObj` before the page is displayed.

**Question:** How do I initialise `myObj` in my controller before the form is loaded?

---

Any better approaches than these are more than welcome!

Comment: Any reasons why you can not use `Default Value Formula` for your custom fields?

Comment: IMHO your Approach 1 in conjunction with `PageReference.getParameters().putAll()` is as good as it gets. Approach 2 will be very [WET](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself) (opposite of DRY) and you don't get the URL parameterization of the input fields for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **Approach2** i would take `ApexPages.StandardController`:

```
public with sharing class YourController{

    private MyObj__c obj;

    public YourController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.obj = (MyObj__c)controller.getRecord();
    }
}
```

[More info about StandardController Class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm)

To **Approach1**.

UPDATE:

It is not a problem to pass date parameter in a current user locale. For that just use `format()` method of the `Date` class:

```
String s = Date.today().format();
```

and then:

```
'/a0H/e?DateField=' + s
```

The s looks for me in europe like `21.02.2013`. In US it will be `02/21/2013`.

[From here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm)

And for the default value of a custom field i would try to use a [Default Value Formula](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_about_default_field_values.htm)

Comment: Thanks, just figured approach 2 out as well! Regarding Approach 1 - the thing is that the parameters are passed via string in a URL so you need `/a0H/e?DateField=02/21/2013` for US users and `/a0H/e?DateField=21.012013` for Europe. My experience has shown you can't mix and match.

Comment: @Marc It is not a problem to pass date parameter in a user locale: `String s = Date.today().format();` and then `'/a0H/e?DateField=' + s`

Comment: @Marc To rebuild the page use `reRender` parameter of any `action` element, like `actionFunction` or `commantButton`.

Comment: Could any one show me the save() code - do I have to make a mySave action and do `upsert obj` or can I wire obj to the standard save method?

Comment: Awesome, thanks @mast03 for Date.format() w/o params!

Comment: @Marc Just like in this example you can use the `save()` method for sure: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm (scroll down for Example)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I wanted to share some working code which illustrates Approach 2 and also shows how to intercept the save method:

#### Page:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="testAccountController">
      <apex:pagemessages /> 
      <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
                <apex:pageBlockButtons > 
                    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Details" columns="1" >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!account.Name}" style="width:300px;"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

#### Controller:

```
    public class testAccountController {
    
        Apexpages.StandardController stdController;
    
        public testAccountController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
            this.stdController = stdController;
            Account acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
            if (acct.id == null) {
              // Set defaults for new records here
              // This is for fields that can still be changed in the page
              acct.CurrencyIsoCode = someFunction();
            }
        }
    
        public pageReference save() {
            // Get the secord being saved
            Account acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
            // Validate or make adjustments
            if (acct.id == null) {
              // Set defaults for new records here
              // This is for fields that should not be changed in the page
            }
            try {
              return stdController.save();
            } catch (Exception e) {
              ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, e.getMessage()));
            }
            return null;
        }
    
    }
```